# Cannot change the value of radio button according to a number added by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the radio button according to a value entered by a user.

So if the value is 4 or more, I need to change the radio button to check the value `Yes`.
Else to check `No`.

Here is the script:

```
<td>a) Right <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 50px" name="right_result" id="right_result">/10 </td>
   <td style="vertical-align: middle">
   <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="monofilament_right_left" id="monofilament_right_left" value="Yes">Yes
   <input type="radio" class="radio" name="monofilament_right_left" id="monofilament_right_left" value="No">No
</td>
```

And the jQuery script:

```
$("#right_result").on('keyup', function(){
    var right_result = $("#right_result").val();
    //console.log(right_result)
    if(right_result>=4){
      $('input[id="monofilament_right_left"]:checked').val("Yes")
    }
})
```

The value is not changing when  the user is adding the number in the text box.

I tried the solution

Comment: I saw the post and didn't helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some additional classes to select the radio buttons.

One thing to note is that IDs should be unique, you shouldn't use the same ID on two elements. That's why I've done this with classes.

This should work:

```js
$("#right_result").on('keyup', function(){
    var right_result = $("#right_result").val();
    
    if(right_result>=4){
      $('.yes-value').prop('checked', true);
    } else if (right_result>0 && right_result<4) {
      $('.no-value').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('.yes-value, .no-value').prop('checked', false)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>a) Right <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 50px" name="right_result" id="right_result">/10 </td>
   <td style="vertical-align: middle">
   <input type="radio" class="radio-inline yes-value" name="monofilament_right_left" value="Yes">Yes
   <input type="radio" class="radio no-value" name="monofilament_right_left" value="No">No
</td>
```

Comment: and how to reset it if the text box is empty ?

Comment: So if the textbox is now blank I don't want any of the options to be selected

Comment: The answer has been updated now. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use different `id` for each `radio` like the following:

```js
$("#right_result").on('keyup', function(){
    var right_result = $("#right_result").val();
    //console.log(right_result)
    if(right_result>=4){
      $('#monofilament_right_left1').prop("checked", true);
    }
    else{
      $('#monofilament_right_left2').prop("checked", true);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>a) Right <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 50px" name="right_result" id="right_result">/10 </td>
   <td style="vertical-align: middle">
   <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="monofilament_right_left" id="monofilament_right_left1" value="Yes">Yes
   <input type="radio" class="radio" name="monofilament_right_left" id="monofilament_right_left2" value="No">No
</td>
```